# Cold Iron Handwraps of Mighty Blows

Tags: pathfinder-2e, unarmed-combat, special-materials

[Handwraps of Mighty Blows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=441) can have runes, so your unarmed attacks benefit from these:

> These handwraps have weapon runes etched into them to give your unarmed attacks the benefits of those runes, making your unarmed attacks work like magic weapons.

Can I use special materials on them as well, making my unarmed attacks Cold Iron or Silver?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Most likely not*

The rules for special [materials](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=729) state the following:

> Most materials are metals; they can be used to make metal weapons and armor. The GM is the final arbiter of what items can be made using a material

While "Most materials are metals" is not a useful statement, because obviously some are not, this strongly implies that special materials substitute similar normal materials. Special woods substitute normal wood, and special metals substitute normal metals. As Handwraps are "embroidered strips of cloth", metal can't be used to replace the cloth.

*Now, your GM might disagree and might allow it (The rules for special materials state that a GM is the final arbiter), but they should probably adhere to the pretty obvious intention behind the special materials. as laid out with the example of the special metals.

Comment: You've never seen metal thread in cloth I assume?

Comment: @Yakk you beat me to it. I know gold has been woven into fabrics but Im sure other metals could be as well. Cloth of gold for instance.

Comment: @Yakk No, actually, but that imo does not change anything. The Special Materials make it quite clear that they replace what the Item is made of, not that they are simply included in the normal material.

Comment: @Patta I would disagree.  The craft rules you linked describe 10%-100% of initial material being the precious material, and continued crafting material costs could be 0%.  This quite explicitly permits making a 10% silver magical item (by weight) up to 8th level.

Comment: If your GM is willing to allow it, you could reskin the wraps to something like ~~brass~~ cold iron knuckles. Same rules, but the material matches the skin.

Comment: Except that those are already weapons that exist in the game. So you would reskin an Item that is explicitly not a weapon with the skin of an existing weapon. I suspect not every GM will go along with that.

Answer (score 5):

### No

> These handwraps have weapon runes etched into them to give your unarmed attacks the benefits of those runes, making your unarmed attacks work like magic weapons.

This magic item causes all of your unarmed attacks to gain the runes etched into the *[handwraps](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=441)*, but there's no mention of the same applying for precious materials. Without that your unarmed attacks wouldn't be affected by the *handwraps'* material.

Unless you're using the *handwraps* as an improvised weapon there's not much reason to craft them from something precious like cold iron or silver.

Comment: How do you etch runes into cloth?

Comment: @Fering with acid for example. A modern example would be with a laser, but acid just works as well